# Layout not showing in tab host

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have used TabHost in my app. I followed the tutorial to implement it. It is working well but on clicking the tabs the specified layout is not shown. Here is the code. Please Help

```
public class HelpScreen extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.inst_manual);

        TabHost host = getTabHost();

        TabSpec btnHelp = host.newTabSpec("Buttons Help");
        btnHelp.setIndicator("Buttons Help",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.brushes_help));
        Intent buttonsHelp = new Intent(HelpScreen.this, ButtonsHelp.class);
        btnHelp.setContent(buttonsHelp);

        TabSpec drawHelp = host.newTabSpec("Drawing Help");
        drawHelp.setIndicator("Drawing Help",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.brushes_help));
        Intent drawingHelp = new Intent(HelpScreen.this, DrawingHelp.class);
        drawHelp.setContent(drawingHelp);

        host.addTab(btnHelp);
        host.addTab(drawHelp);
    }
}

public class ButtonsHelp extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.buttons_help);
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to create intents like this ...

```
Intent buttonsHelp = new Intent().setClass(this, ButtonsHelp.class);
Intent drawingHelp = new Intent().setClass(this, DrawingHelp.class);
```

Comment: Thats weird, its working for me. What is happening when you click the other button ? i mean what layout is shown ?

Comment: "Button Click"
btnHelp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
   Intent i = new Intent(this, HelpScreen.class);
   startActivity(i);
 }
        });
And rest of the code is in question.